# select parent and grand parent using shortcuts

Tags: xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<list>
 <list.item> This s the first list item
  <list>
    <list.item> This s the Second list item <page>3</page>
    </list.item>
  </list>
 </list.item>
</list>
```

Here , i want to see the parents of `page`, i want to select using `..` like shortcuts, i'm trying to go to main `list` using, `../../../../..[list]`, but it is not accepting it.

please let me know where am i going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..` or `parent::node()` would select any parent node, `parent::list` any `list` parent element. And `../..` or `parent::node()/parent::node()` would select any grandparent node while `../parent::list` would select any grandparent `list` element. There is also the `ancestor` axis so `ancestor::list` would select any ancestor `list` elements. But if you want to select the root element then `/list` would do without having to walk up the tree along the parent axis.

For your `page` element you could use `ancestor::list[last()]` or `/list` or `../../../parent::list` to select the ancestor list element up the hierarchy four levels.

Comment: Hi @Martin. thanks for the reply, i tried this, but still facing some issues, can you please share your email address, since the documents that i'm working on are confidential, and i'm unable to know how to get the result. Thanks

Comment: @user3872094 I'm not sure moving this discussion off-site is a good idea. Nobody else will be able to profit from the answers. SO is meant to help everyone that encounters the same problem you are facing. Try to identify your key difficulties and model an XML sample that reflects them well.

Comment: Here the problem is, though there is no `list` above `list`, the match is getting caught, that's why i'm asking for your favour